# Rails: Find all children from the same generation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, tree, orgchart

In my application I have positions. Each position has one parent and many children positions. How can I navigate the tree and find all positions that are in the same generation?

Currently I have this:

```
def org_chart_level
  ps = self
  level = 10
  while ps do
    break if ps.reports_to == nil
    ps = ps.reports_to
    level += 10
  end
  if self.reports_to
    siblings = self.reports_to.responsible_for
  else
    siblings = [self]
    puts siblings
  end
  "#{level}-#{siblings.index(self) + 1}"
end
```

This almost works because it can give me the level of a position and it can tell me which sibling it is of the parent, but it cannot tell me which sibling it is in the generation.

Expected level for each position.

```
1.1
  -2.1
     -3.1
  -2.2
     -3.2
```

Actual level:

```
1.1
  -2.1
     -3.1
  -2.2
     -3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the positions generation in the database before it is saved.

`before_save :find_generation`

```
def find_generation
  ps = self
  i = 0
  while ps do
    break if ps.reports_to == nil
    ps = ps.reports_to
    i += 1
  end
  self.generation = i
end
```

And then when I need to generate the org chart level:

```
def org_chart_level
  ps = self
  level = 10
  while ps do
    break if ps.reports_to == nil
    ps = ps.reports_to
    level += 10
  end
  generation = organization.positions.where(generation: self.generation) #position belongs to organization.
  "#{level}-#{generation.index(self) + 1}"
end
```